# Check if textbox is blank in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, textbox

I have a email textbox in my web page.
When user submits the page I am doing some client side validation using javascript.
I can get the value of the textbox and compare it to know if it has any data or not.
But in case user enters only blank spaces how will I bypass it.

I am using below mentioned code.

```
// Check the format of email only if it has some data.
// otherwise no checking is needed.
if ($('#txtEmail').val() != "")
{
     // do something
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `if ($('#txtEmail').val().length)` this would do too...

Comment: Thanks all for the responses. 
.length is not working. When more than one space is entered then .length returns the number of spaces.
Trim is useful.

Comment: well you can use the trim first then .length :) `if ($.trim($('#txtEmail').val()).length)`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `$.trim()` function to remove all white-space from beginning and end of the string

```
if ($.trim($('#txtEmail').val()) != "")
{
     // do something
}
```

Comment: `.trim()` should not be used that way... it causes problems on one of the old browsers :) `if ($.trim($('#txtEmail').val()) != "")` instead :)

Answer (score 3):

javascript

```
if((document.getElementById('bereich').value).length==0)
```

or jquery

```
if ($('#txtEmail').val()).length==0)
```

or

```
  if ($.trim($('#txtEmail').val()).length==0)
```

Comment: @AnkitGautam - for your kind info that y i used lenght....and anyway i updated answer with trim also